# React js map() undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I am new to React and I am going a little crazy trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. I am trying to iterate through a json array that I get from an ajax call. When I mock the data it works perfectly, but when I make an ajax call to get the exact same data it gives me `undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.state.list.map()')`

the array:

`[ { "name": "drop1" }, { "name": "drop2" }, { "name": "drop3" } ]`

the function:

```
var List = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
   return {data: {}};
 },
 componentDidMount: function() {
   $.ajax({
       url: ACTUAL_URL,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data){
         this.setState({data: data});
       }.bind(this),
       error: function(xhr, status, err){
         console.error(url, status, err.toString());
       }.bind(this)
     });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ul className="droplist">
        {this.state.data.map(function(l){
           return (<li>{l.name}</li>)
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Additionally to the provided answer: you normally don't perform ajax requests from a component.

Comment: @zerkms Disagree, normally you would if you're not using Flux.

Comment: @limelights even if you're not following Flux - you need to use some other architectural design pattern that separates presentation from persistence and business logic.

Comment: @zerkms No, I still disagree. I've made widgets that need to be self contained using React. There it makes sense to do this.

Comment: @limelights being self-contained does not mean that everything should be placed in a single object. Every object should be responsible for one small aspect. Don't you agree the provided code is hard to test?

Comment: @zerkms are you saying that I should pull it out into a separate function? In the react tutorial they place the ajax call in the componentDidMount section

Comment: @this_is_ender the tutorial makes an accent on introducing you into the basics, not into the best application design practices. Which is in fact a completely different story and is not too much relevant to React itself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change your `getInitialState()`. 
Currently your data is an object literal and object literals doesn't support `map()`.
Change it to an array.

Comment: Wow... that was a simple fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was trying to use [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) but my data actually was an object rather than array so using `Object.keys(data)` is the right way to iterate over objects:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(item => {...});
// OR
Object.keys(data).map(item => {...});
```

[Read details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)